# CI active record style sql queries

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am new in `Code Igniter` and like its `active record` feature now is there any useful **steps** or **tips** or any **guidness** how do i convert my pervoiusly written simple `SQL Queries` in `CI` style like this is my perviouly written **simple query**

```
SELECT * 
FROM   hs_albums 
WHERE  id NOT IN (SELECT album_id 
                  FROM   hs_delete_albums 
                 WHERE  user_id = 72 
                         AND del_type = 1) 
       AND ( created = 72 
              OR club_id IN (SELECT cbs.id 
                             FROM   hs_clubs cbs 
                                    INNER JOIN hs_club_permissions cbp 
                                            ON cbs.id = cbp.club_id 
                             WHERE  cbp.user_id = 72 
                                    AND cbp.status = 2) 
              OR group_id IN (SELECT gps.id 
                              FROM   hs_groups gps 
                                     INNER JOIN hs_group_permissions grp 
                                             ON gps.id = grp.group_id 
                              WHERE  grp.user_id = 72 
                                     AND grp.status = 2) 
              OR comp_id IN (SELECT cmp.id 
                             FROM   hs_companies cmp 
                                    INNER JOIN hs_comp_permissions comp 
                                            ON cmp.id = comp.comp_id 
                             WHERE  comp.user_id = 72 
                                    AND comp.status = 2) )
```

Comment: CI does not support sub-query

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: **You don't**.

CodeIgniter's Active Record implementation is basically a layer on top of SQL that makes writing queries easier by:

- Automatically escaping values
- Automatically generating the appropriate query syntax for the database, so that the application can be more easily ported between databases (for instance, if you didn't use Active Record to write a query, and then wanted to move from MySQL to PostgreSQL, then you might well need to rewrite the query to make it work with PostgreSQL)
- Providing a syntax for queries in PHP directly, thus avoiding the context switching between PHP and SQL.

However, it can't do everything SQL can do, and while I would always try to use ActiveRecord where possible, there comes a point where you're better off forgetting about using it and just using `$this->db->query()` to write your query directly. In this case, as mamdouh alramadan has said, CodeIgniter doesn't support subqueries so you can't replicate this query using ActiveRecord anyway.

The thing to remember is that ActiveRecord is a tool, not a requirement. If you're using CodeIgniter and aren't using an ORM instead, you should use it for the reasons mentioned above. However, once it starts getting in the way, you should consider whether it would be better practice to write your query manually instead.